# Correct .bash_profile in OSX

Tags: macos, bash

I need to use some tools, but I have some problems when I try use PHP Artisan in Laravel and Cordova, I need to comment some lines, because the $PATH is not working fine. I am a noob working with Unix :)

To be more specific in my question, I need that these lines work fine together, without need to uncomment and comment depending of the tool I need to use:

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Errors I have when I uncommented each one:

> **Case 1:** Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.
>
> **Case 2:** Mcrypt PHP extension required.

**EDIT:** I've added the complete bash profile:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source /Users/chema/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source /Users/chema/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc

#Comment this line make Cordova works fine
#export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/chema/sd$
#Comment this line make PHP Artisan with Laravel works fine
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

If I uncomment the two lines, just works PHP Artisan Laravel.

**echo PATH** when Cordova it's working and PHP Artisan doesn't:

**which xcodebuild** /usr/bin/xcodebuild

> /Users/chema/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users/chema/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk$:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/tools:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/platform-tools

**echo PATH** when PHP Artisan it's working and Cordova doesn't:

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Users/chema/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk$:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/tools:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/platform-tools

**which xcodebuild** /usr/bin/xcodebuild

Thanks!!

Comment: instead of `PATH=${PATH}:...` try doing: `export PATH=$PATH:...`

Comment: @sircapsalot What difference will that make?

Comment: Who knows... i'm still sort of new to bash, give me a break `:)` just offering a potential solution.  hence why i didn't make it an answer

Comment: @sircapsalot Fine.  The `{` `}` characters can be used to delimit an environment variable reference; so you can do something like `echo ${HOME}hello` where `echo $HOMEhello` would obviously fail.  The `(` `)` characters, on the other hand, are a different story.

Comment: and putting `PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` ; export PATH as the last line (and commenting the others out? doesn't work

Comment: @Doon I don't have any problem with Android... I have rewritten my question to be more specific.

Comment: You don't need to export after each line. All I did was combine all your path statements into 1 line, and export it.  You say it doesn't work, but how exactly does it not work? what error do you get?

Comment: @Doon I have the same problem, the other App doesn't work...

Comment: @Doon If I put like you say, PHP Artisan works, but Cordova not. The error in Cordova is: Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.

Comment: Please update your question with the following information:  the output of your complete path statement `echo $PATH` when cordova doesn't work, along with `which xcodebuild` when cordova doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65284/discussion-between-doon-and-chemitaxis).

Comment: What is the output of `xcodebuild -version` and `xcode-select --print-path` for both configurations?

Comment: xcodebuild: error: invalid option '--print-path'

Comment: hi @chemitaxis, did you found a solution to your problem? have the same issue, :( thanks

Answer (score 2):

ok after some digging. I think I've figured this out

What is happening is that `head` command that Cordova needs which normally lives in `/usr/bin/head` on OSX, is being overshawdowed by a version supplied by XAMPP.  So the path order needs to be adjusted.   A `which head` when XAMPP is uncommented should probably give you `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/head`  as opposed to `/usr/bin/head`

That being said try making your path as follows.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

This should put the xampp version of head at the end of your path.  But this might cause other name collisions that cause XAMPP not to work (I don't have either installed so cannot test) (also removed the the `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/chema/sdk-android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/chema/sd$` which was adding what looked like redundant /wrong paths into your path)

IF this still doesn't work, your best bet might be to create a wrapper script to run cordova,  something that sets the path to one you know works and then just passes the command line options along

--edit--

on OSX path is built up by the `path_helper`  which builds up the path from `/etc/paths` && `/etc/manpaths` This is run from you shells init code `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zshenv`, etc.. and sets up the base PATH

based on your comment of head still being the one in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`  it appears that this line `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` is either not being executed,  or `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` was already in the PATH from somewhere else (IE you keep sourcing your .bashrc, or the like as opposed to creating a new shell, etc..  )

So try this. put the following in reset_paths.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export PATH
```

what this will do is reset your path, execute path_helper to set the paths from the OS, and then tack on so we are starting fresh..

then in your shell do `source ./reset_paths.sh`

then try to run Cordova  from that shell and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I will test later, at home!! ;)

Comment: Sorry @Doon, it's not working... :( I have created a bounty... thanks

Comment: what is error message with above? and what does `which head` show

Comment: This is my head:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/head

Comment: can you tell me more details about create a wrapper script to run cordova? Thx!

Comment: this `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/head ` leads me to believe that your don't have `/usr/bin/` in your path before your xampp.  So when you are testing. How are you changing your path for testing.  are you createing new logins shells or testing from the cli, and just rexporting.